# Generating a matrix

Tags: matrix

> Generate a 100 × 100 matrix

```
A = matrix(100, 100, lambda i, j: 1/(i-j) if i != j else 0)
```

I want the numerical value of `A`'s determinant. Is it quicker to evaluate
the determinant exactly first or to work from the start with a
matrix with numerical entries?

Note: this matrix is given in Sage syntax, how would I write this in Mathematica syntax?

I know how to create a 100 x 100 matrix:

```
A[i_, j_] := Table[{i} {j}, {i, 100}, {j, 100}]
```

Any help wil be appreciated.

Comment: For searching purposes: this is a particular example of a Cauchy matrix.

Comment: It's also Toeplitz.

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 100;
A = Array[{i, j} \[Function] If[i != j, 1/(i - j), 0], {n, n}];
```

or

```
A = Table[If[i != j, 1/(i - j), 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
```

The latter is actually faster.

If you need it even faster, use

```
A = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},Table[If[i != j, 1/(i - j), 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]][
 n
];
```

That's about 20 times faster.

**Edit**

With the remark by [AccidentalFourierTransform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34893),

```
A = ToeplitzMatrix[
  Join[{0}, 1/Range[1, n - 1]], Join[{0}, -1/Range[1, n - 1]]
  ];
```

is another very fast possibility.

Comment: Interesting that the `Table` version is faster. I’d have expected similar speed given that the auto compilation should be able to handle both equivalently.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I was also surprised. Maybe `Array` does not compile? I use it rather scarcely an now I know it's for some reason ;)

Comment: @b3m2a1 Actually, I also wonder about the speed difference between (`n = 1000`, so above the compile threashold)  `Table[If[i != j, 1/(i - j), 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]`,  `With[{cf = 
    Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}}, If[i != j, 1/(i - j), 0]]},
  Table[cf[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
  ]` (factor 2) and `Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
  Table[If[i != j, 1/(i - j), 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]][n]` (another factor 10). Why isn't Mathematica using the latter?

Answer (score 3):

I shortened the matrix for demonstration.

```
{ii, ji} = {10, 10};
B = Table[If[i != j, 1/(i - j), 0], {i, 1, ii}, {j, 1, ji}];
MatrixForm[%]
Det[%]
N[%]
```

The output matrix

$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{5} & -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{7} & -\frac{1}{8} & -\frac{1}{9} \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{5} & -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{7} & -\frac{1}{8} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{5} & -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{7} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{5} & -\frac{1}{6} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{5} \\
 \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}$

$\frac{2018199369318664984321}{878245079040000000000}$

Determinant = 2.29799